# Graph of $ \ \arccos\circ \cos$

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x)=\arccos(cosx).$

$f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow   [0,\pi]  $

When  $x \in [0+2k\pi,\pi+2k\pi]$,  $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ we have $f(x)=x.$

How to prove that for $x \in [\pi+2k\pi,2\pi+2k\pi]$ we have $f(x)=-x$ ?

Comment: Differentiate $f$ on the second interval and conclude.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. True is: When $x∈[0+2kπ,π+2kπ]$, $k∈\Bbb Z$ we have $f(x)=x-2kπ$. Or $f(2kπ+x)=x$.

Consider that for $x∈[-π,0]$ you get because of the even symmetry of the cosine $f(x)=f(-x)=-x$.